# Summing two dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two following dictionaries with same keys but different values:

```
dict1 = {"a": [{"b":1, "c":1, "d":[{"e":1, "f":1}]}]}
dict2 = {"a": [{"b":2, "c":2, "d":[{"e":2, "f":2}]}]}
```

I need to sum these dictionaries and get the following result:

```
res = {"a": [{"b":3, "c":3, "d":[{"e":3, "f":3}]}]}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: as you can see there are values which are lists and some member of these lists can also be a lists, so I have some difficulties to solve the problem, will be glad to see some example..

Comment: That doesn't answer my question; please note that SO isn't a code-writing service. Take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: Understood, I am new here, actually this is my very first question. Next time I definitely will post what I've tried to do in order to solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is recursive approach:

```
dict1 = {"a": [{"b":1, "c":1, "d":[{"e":1, "f":1}]}]}
dict2 = {"a": [{"b":2, "c":2, "d":[{"e":2, "f":2}]}]}

def add_objs(d1, d2):
    if isinstance(d1, dict):
        return {k: add_objs(d1[k], d2[k]) for k in d1}
    if isinstance(d1, list):
        return [add_objs(a, b) for a, b in zip(d1, d2)]
    return d1+d2

add_objs(dict1, dict2)
# {'a': [{'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': [{'e': 3, 'f': 3}]}]}
```

This assumes that `d1` and `d2` have the exact same inner structure, all dicts have the same keys, all lists the same length, etc.